# Avoiding nested if else statement ladder in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

It's hard to find answers to this problem when you don't know exactly how to describe it...

What is the most idiomatic way to deal with a fairly deep (but fixed) nested set of tests that you want to run sequentially but terminate as soon as the first one comes up with a successful result?

Instead of the following

**Option 1:** (results in way too much indentation)

```
def make_decision():

    results = ... some code or function that returns a list or None
    if results:
        decision = random.choice(results)
    else:
        results = ... other code or function
        if results:
            decision = random.choice(results)
        else:
            results = ... other code or function
            if results:
                decision = random.choice(results)
            else:
                results = ... other code or function
                if results:
                    decision = random.choice(results)

      ...etc.

                                else:
                                    decision = None

    print(decision)

    return decision
```

**Option 2**

Another option is to return from the function early but I'm not sure it's good practice to have so many returns scattered about and in this case I would prefer to do one final thing at the end (e.g. `print(decision)`) before returning:

```
def make_decision():

    results = ... some code or function that returns a list or None
    if results:
        return random.choice(results)
    
    results = ... other code or function
    if results:
        return random.choice(results)

    results = ... other code or function
    if results:
        return random.choice(results)
    
    ...etc.

    return None
```

**Option 3**

Finally I could make each test a separate function [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638292/python-process-flow-avoiding-nested-if-statements) and call them iteratively, provided each test function has the same set of arguments.

```
def test1(args):
    ...

def test2(args):
    ...

def test3(args):
    ...

def make_decision():

    decision = None
    for test in [test1, test2, test3, ...]:
        results = test(args)
        if results:
            decision = random.choice(results)
            break

    print(decision)

    return decision
```

This looks the best but I hadn't planned to make a function for every test and some tests can be done with the same function but with different arguments and some are just one-liners whereas others are multiple lines.  So then would I have to build a list of functions and arguments before starting the loop?  Or make a list of [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html) functions?

Any better suggestions welcome (before I go ahead with option 3 above)

UPDATE 2018-07-21:

**A future potential option**

Unbeknown to me as I was wrestling with this problem, [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) was approved (and Mr van Rossum resigned as a consequence).  If this PEP is implemented the following solution will also be possible I think:

```
def make_decision():

    if (results := ... some code or function) is not None:
        decision = random.choice(results)
    elif (results := ... some code or function) is not None:
        decision = random.choice(results)
    
    ...etc.

    else:
        decision = None

    return decision
```

Comment: You gave three options. What do you expect from us? Make a choicr for you? On what basis?

Comment: Thanks @KlausD.  To confirm: I wanted confirmation that I have identified all the options and there are no better ones.  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: It's kind of hard for me to think what would be the best choice without knowing the underlying operation you're trying to do. But I'd like to add you could use `try/except` blocks too. Maybe catching a specific exception speeds up the resolution?

Comment: Its an 'expert' computer player of a simple board game.  `test1` is very trivial - is it the first move of the game.  `test2` looks for an obvious winning move.  `test3` looks to block the any opponent winning moves but can do this with the same function used in `test2` only with argument `role=opponent` instead of `role=self`, `test4, ..., test8` do more sophisticated (computationally) analysis of the game state.

Comment: I think your Option 2 is somewhat broken. The `else` at the end is orphaned (syntactically it isn't but logically it seems misplaced). If you want to go for something similar you'd need to set some value in all of the `if` branches that you use later on to decide if (logically) an `else` applies.

Comment: The last `else` in Option 2 is supposed to be attached to the last if statement in the chain.  I.e. if the last test also fails, it returns None.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with early `return` statements. In fact, that is almost always clearer and preferable to a single return at the bottom of the function. Combine that with your third option. That is, don't `break` . once you have the answer, just `return` it. Then turn the outermost `return` into a "can't happen" error or whatever fallback makes sense.

Comment: The one problem with the return method is I want to do one final thing at the end before exiting...

Comment: The recommendations [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#returning-values) suggest "in order to keep a clear intent and a sustainable readability level, it is preferable to avoid returning meaningful values from many output points in the body."

Comment: I amended the else statement in Option 2 as I think @yaccob was suggesting.

Comment: I forgot how the else statement looked before, but as it is now, you can simply remove the else, since the last if anyway returns. (Furthermore there is the `etc...` between the if and the else ...)
If you want to "do one final thing at the end before exiting" I would recommend a try with a finally block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, this is obvious now that re-look at it:

```
def make_decision():

    results = ... some code or function that returns a list or None

    if results is None:
        results = ... other code or function

    if results is None:
        results = ... other code or function

    ...etc.

    if results is None:
        decision = None
    else:
        decision = random.choice(results)
    print(decision)

    return decision
```

Comment: How's this different?

Comment: Sorry John I don't think I understand your answer.  I thought you were suggesting `elif`.  I don't think `elif` works.  Or please provide your proposed code in your answer.  If it's the same as this I will remove this answer.

Comment: I propose you go with either 2 or 3.

Comment: I went with my answer above for the reasons articulated in comments above.  It looks cleaner and does the job...

Comment: Not sure why someone is down-voting this.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any of the options, it all depends on your preference. On Option 2, I don't think it's a bad idea to have many `return`s since they are enclosed in conditional code. They will only be executed if that condition is `True`.

On Option 1, you can decide to switch to `elif results:` instead of:

```
if results:
        # some code
    else:
        if results:
               # some code
```

In your code it almost seem like you're checking for same `results` which looks like only one `if` block will execute. You should be checking against some value e.g. `if results == something`.

Finally, Option 3 looks cleaner. And to wrap up, pick the one you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks.  The `elif` would be ideal but I need to capture the results of each test first before testing them (`results` is a list of good moves or an empty list).  Is there a way to do that within an `elif` condition?

Comment: In that case you should choose between Option 2 and 3.

Comment: See the answer I just came up with.

Comment: Where is the answer you came up with?

Comment: It should be [showing above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51227284/1609514)